# how to get the value ot text node with jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="count">5</div>
<div class="count">6</div>
```

How do I get the values of the text nodes? If I use text() method, it concatenates both values.

Comment: actually I need to set the width of div using the value it contains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use map if you want an array of the text values, eg.

```
$('div.class').map(function() { return $(this).text(); })
```

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
$("div.count:first").text();
```

if you have several and want to get 3rd for instance you could do

```
$("div.count:eq(2)").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to loop the collection that results from `$(".count")`, and then grab the `text()` value of each in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$(".count:first").text()
$(".count:last").text()
```